# jquery or javascript to make listbox content drag and drop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

table name - news
I am selecting data from database and displaying in select box/option box.

**Now I need to up and down selected rows inside option box.**

for that **I need javascript or jquery to make listbox content dragable and dropable.**

plz suggest me how to make this select tag values drag and drop.

below is my code..

```
    <select id="result_sub" name="remove_sub_top_news" size="10" style="width:400px; border:1px solid #BBBBBB; float:left; overflow:auto">
            <?php                  
            foreach($sub_top_select as $sub_top)
            {                       
            ?>          
    <option id="recordsArray_<?php echo $sub_top['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $sub_top["id"]; ?>">
<?php echo $sub_top["headline"]; ?></option>
            <?php }?>           
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jqueryui

see this link

[draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

[droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)